# How load javafx.scene.image.Image by demand?

Tags: java, image, javafx

Is it possible to discard loaded content of [Image](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) and later load it again? Is it possible to load it on demand?

Can I have [ImageView](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) which loads it's image only on show?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. `Image` represents a fixed set of image data, if that is what you mean. `WritableImage` represents an image of fixed size, but the pixel data can be changed after instantiation via its `PixelWriter`. I have no idea what you mean by "Can I have ImageView which loads it's image only on show?".

Comment: @James_D because they made `Image` to be loadfble with delay. See methods like `cancel()` and `isBackgroundLoading()`. It is strange, that this process can go in only one direction, like in thermodynamics law.

Comment: Hmm, not entirely sure what you mean. However, the solution to your problem is to keep a fixed set of `ImageView`s (enough to tile the display under any values of the scrolling offsets) and update their `Image` properties as needed. Calling `setImage()` on an image view will force it to repaint; if you use background loading it will repaint itself when loading is complete, which is what you want. It would be wise to call `cancel()` on the current `Image` before replacing it, to prevent unnecessary work in the background. Replaced images will be gc'd in the usual way.

Comment: Are you trying to create an interface similar to "Google Maps"? So you have the view represented by some "tiles", each tile showing an image. The user can "pan" (scroll), so newly-exposed tiles have to load a new image, while other images go off-screen?

Comment: Yes regard google maps. Also regard loading each tile from FXML. Also regard any other case when part of the graph is loaded on show (ultimately common case)

Comment: OK, can you [edit] your question to make it clear what you're actually asking. Instead of asking about your attempted solution, state (clearly) the actual problem you are trying to solve, then go on to describe what you have attempted. Right now this is an [x-y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Okay, I have edited my this question and also gave a correct answer for it, which I already investigated.

Comment: But you made the question worse, and your answer is utterly useless to anyone else who actually wants to solve the problem you're addressing.

Comment: For me it is pretty useful to know if something is not covered by contract. I spent several hours to learn it. Later people will find an answer immediately.

Comment: Isn't five minutes scanning the methods in the [Javadocs for `Image`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) sufficient to conclude that there is no mechanism to update the image? I agree it would be nice if they stated it explicitly in the description of the class, but it doesn't take long to see that the only reference to the source of the image is passed into the constructor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, there is no such functionality in `Image` contract. Image can load in background, but once loaded, it cannot be unloaded.

If using `ImageView`, then you should assign `Image` to it explicitly, but JavaFX doesn't provide a way for you to know when `ImageView` is actually shown.

To implement required close to `ImageView`, I was to fork it and highly utilize deprecated API with `Prism`, including `NGImageView` class.

Comment: But you can use an `ImageView` to do the same thing.

Comment: If you know then answer. Don't play hide-n-seek.

Comment: Working on it... It is not trivial and will take some time to write up.

Comment: Not trivial is like writing you own `ImageView` as I did, or more trivial?

Comment: There is no need to do that. Just (essentially) manage the layout yourself, so that you load new images (if needed) when the image view comes into view. See my answer (and github examples, as the complete examples are a little long).

Answer (score 1):

The `Image` class is essentially immutable with respect to its image data, in the sense that you can specify a source for the image data at construction time, and then cannot modify it via the API subsequently.

The `ImageView` class provides functionality for displaying an image in the UI. The `ImageView` class is mutable, in the sense that you can change the image it displays.

The basic strategy you need to implement "tiled images" functionality is to create a *virtualized container*, which has a collection of "cells" or "tiles" which are reused to display different content. This is essentially how controls such as `ListView`, `TableView`, and `TreeView` are implemented in JavaFX. You may also be interested in Tomas Mikula's [Flowless](https://github.com/TomasMikula/Flowless) implementation of the same kind of idea.

So to implement "tiled images" functionality, you could use an array of `ImageView`s as the "cells" or "tiles". You can place these in a pane and implement panning/scrolling in the pane, and when image views scroll out of view, reuse the `ImageView`s by moving the images from one image view to another, loading new images only for the tiles that need it. Obviously, images that are no longer referenced by any image view will be eligible for garbage collection in the usual way.

There are probably other ways to achieve this, such as using `WritableImage`s and using a `PixelWriter` to update the pixel data when needed. Which works best probably depends somewhat on which is most convenient for the actual format you have for the image data; there is probably little performance difference between different strategies.

If you are loading the images from a server or database, you should do so in the background. If the image is loaded from a URL, the `Image` class provides functionality to do this directly. If you are loading from an input stream (e.g. from a database BLOB field), you will need to implement the background threading yourself.

Here is the basic idea (no threading):

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PanningTilesExample extends Application {

    private static final int TILE_WIDTH = 100;
    private static final int TILE_HEIGHT = 100;

    private static final int PANE_WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int PANE_HEIGHT = 800;

    // amount scrolled left, in pixels:
    private final DoubleProperty xOffset = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    // amount scrolled right, in pixels:
    private final DoubleProperty yOffset = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

    // number of whole tiles shifted to left:
    private final IntegerProperty tileXOffset = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    // number of whole tiles shifted up:
    private final IntegerProperty tileYOffset = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    private final Pane pane = new Pane();

    // for enabling dragging:
    private double mouseAnchorX;
    private double mouseAnchorY;

    // array of ImageViews:
    private ImageView[][] tiles;

    private final Random rng = new Random();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // update number of tiles offset when number of pixels offset changes:
        tileXOffset.bind(xOffset.divide(TILE_WIDTH));
        tileYOffset.bind(yOffset.divide(TILE_HEIGHT));

        // create the images views, etc. This method could be called
        // when the pane size changes, if you want a resizable pane with fixed size tiles:
        build();

        // while tile offsets change, allocate new images to existing image views:

        tileXOffset.addListener(
                (obs, oldOffset, newOffset) -> rotateHorizontal(oldOffset.intValue() - newOffset.intValue()));

        tileYOffset.addListener(
                (obs, oldOffset, newOffset) -> rotateVertical(oldOffset.intValue() - newOffset.intValue()));

        // Simple example just has a fixed size pane: 
        pane.setMinSize(PANE_WIDTH, PANE_HEIGHT);
        pane.setPrefSize(PANE_WIDTH, PANE_HEIGHT);
        pane.setMaxSize(PANE_WIDTH, PANE_HEIGHT);


        // enable panning on pane (just update offsets when dragging):

        pane.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            mouseAnchorX = e.getSceneX();
            mouseAnchorY = e.getSceneY();
        });

        pane.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            double deltaX = e.getSceneX() - mouseAnchorX;
            double deltaY = e.getSceneY() - mouseAnchorY;
            xOffset.set(xOffset.get() + deltaX);
            yOffset.set(yOffset.get() + deltaY);
            mouseAnchorX = e.getSceneX();
            mouseAnchorY = e.getSceneY();
        });

        // display in stage:
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void build() {

        // create array of image views:

        int numTileCols = (int) (PANE_WIDTH / TILE_WIDTH + 2);
        int numTileRows = (int) (PANE_HEIGHT / TILE_HEIGHT + 2);

        tiles = new ImageView[numTileCols][numTileRows];

        // populate array:

        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < numTileCols; colIndex++) {

            final int col = colIndex;

            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numTileRows; rowIndex++) {

                final int row = rowIndex;

                // create actual image view and initialize image:                
                ImageView tile = new ImageView();
                tile.setImage(getImage(col - tileXOffset.get(), row - tileYOffset.get()));
                tile.setFitWidth(TILE_WIDTH);
                tile.setFitHeight(TILE_HEIGHT);

                // position image by offset, and register listeners to keep it updated:
                xOffset.addListener((obs, oldOffset, newOffset) -> {
                    double offset = newOffset.intValue() % TILE_WIDTH + (col - 1) * TILE_WIDTH;
                    tile.setLayoutX(offset);
                });
                tile.setLayoutX(xOffset.intValue() % TILE_WIDTH + (col - 1) * TILE_WIDTH);

                yOffset.addListener((obs, oldOffset, newOffset) -> {
                    double offset = newOffset.intValue() % TILE_HEIGHT + (row - 1) * TILE_HEIGHT;
                    tile.setLayoutY(offset);
                });
                tile.setLayoutY(yOffset.intValue() % TILE_HEIGHT + (row - 1) * TILE_HEIGHT);

                // add image view to pane:
                pane.getChildren().add(tile);

                // store image view in array:
                tiles[col][row] = tile;
            }
        }
    }

    // tiles have been shifted off-screen in vertical direction
    // need to reallocate images to image views, and get new images
    // for tiles that have moved into view:

    // delta represents the number of tiles we have shifted, positive for up
    private void rotateVertical(int delta) {

        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < tiles.length; colIndex++) {


            if (delta > 0) {

                // top delta rows have shifted off-screen
                // shift top row images by delta
                // add new images to bottom rows:

                for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex + delta < tiles[colIndex].length; rowIndex++) {

                    // stop any background loading we no longer need
                    if (rowIndex < delta) {
                        Image current = tiles[colIndex][rowIndex].getImage();
                        if (current != null) {
                            current.cancel();
                        } 
                    }

                    // move image up from lower rows:
                    tiles[colIndex][rowIndex].setImage(tiles[colIndex][rowIndex + delta].getImage());
                }

                // fill lower rows with new images:
                for (int rowIndex = tiles[colIndex].length - delta; rowIndex < tiles[colIndex].length; rowIndex++) {
                    tiles[colIndex][rowIndex].setImage(getImage(-tileXOffset.get() + colIndex, -tileYOffset.get() + rowIndex));
                }
            }

            if (delta < 0) {

                // similar to previous case...
            }
        }

    }


    // similarly, rotate images horizontally:
    private void rotateHorizontal(int delta) {
        // similar to rotateVertical....    
    }

    // get a new image for tile represented by column, row
    // this implementation just snapshots a label, but this could be
    // retrieved from a file, server, or database, etc
    private Image getImage(int column, int row) {
        Label label = new Label(String.format("Tile [%d,%d]", column, row));
        label.setPrefSize(TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);
        label.setMaxSize(TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);
        label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        label.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(randomColor(), CornerRadii.EMPTY , Insets.EMPTY)));

        // must add label to a scene for background to work:
        new Scene(label);
        return label.snapshot(null, null);
    }


    private Color randomColor() {
        return Color.rgb(rng.nextInt(256), rng.nextInt(256), rng.nextInt(256));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Complete code (with thread handling) [here](https://gist.github.com/james-d/a249470377fb3c58784a9349a22641c4), complete version without threading in a [previous revision](https://gist.github.com/james-d/a249470377fb3c58784a9349a22641c4/32b34d0a396826e00ea57ce61cbaafd423e9bc9c)

There is obviously more functionality (and performance enhancements) that could be added here, for example you could allow for resizing the pane (update: the latest version of the gist linked above does this), and create or remove tiles when the pane changes size, etc. But this should function as a basic template for this functionality.

Comment: Updated the gists periodically, I recommend browsing through some of the [revisions](https://gist.github.com/james-d/a249470377fb3c58784a9349a22641c4/revisions).

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to have your  images loaded before they are displayed!

If you wish to get rid of the image simply set the image to null! But you will then have ro reinitialize that image in order to be able to view! I do not recommend this!

If you will reuse that image just keep it memory! 
Load it once and use it on unlimited imageViews!